# Java size of ArrayList of Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created an ArrayList A each element of which further contains an ArrayList. All entries are integers. I wish to then calculate the length of "outer" ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] A = (ArrayList<Integer>[])new ArrayList[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    A[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

How can I use the `size()` or `length()` functions to obtain the result n?

Directly using `A.size()` gives the error `error: cannot find symbol`. This is required because I'm passing A to other functions and do not want to pass n as well every time.

Comment: All this is written in the main. Prior to the snippet I provided, I input n: `int n = scanner.nextInt();` and obtain the error immediately after the snippet when I try to print the length: `System.out.println(A.size());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have created an ArrayList A

Actually, you just created an array **of ArrayLists**.

`A.length` gets you the size of that

`A[index].size()` gets you the sizes of any one list.

---

If you wanted an ArrayList called A

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> A = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use the size() or length() functions to obtain the result n?

The `identifier` `A` is a reference to an array not ArrayList. The Array `A` contains ArrayLists.

below shows how to access the length:

```
 ArrayList<Integer>[] A = (ArrayList<Integer>[])new ArrayList[10];
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    A[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 }
 System.out.println(A.length);
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response!

Answer (score 0):

You should use A[i].size() to obtain size of each array list

Comment: I wanted the size of the "outer" ArrayList, which it turns out isn't an ArrayList at all. I was able to access the internal ones. Thanks though!

Comment: use  A.length for the size of outer array list

Comment: Because it is an Array of ArrayList. So You have to use A.length for the size of array.